# Center and radius of the osculating circle - The limiting position of a circle trough three points

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, frenet-frame, osculating-circle

I am stucked on problem 1.7.2.b of *Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces* by Manfredo do Carmo. The problem is similar as [this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1149928/circle-determined-by-three-points-on-a-curve-tends-to-the-osculating-circle), but here the exercise defines the osculator circle, ie, this circle of exercise is whose we call osculator circle, and is in $\mathbb{R}^3$. My difficult is another of that topic.

> (Adaptated exercise) Let $\alpha(s) \colon I \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be the parametrization by arc length of a curve. Consider a circle that passes through the three points $\alpha(0)$, $\alpha(h_1)$, and $\alpha(h_2)$.  Prove that as $(h_1, h_2) \to (0, 0)$, the limiting position of this circle has center at the line that contains $n(0)$ and radius $1/k(0)$.

We can consider the canonical form of the curve at $0$.

As some similar exercises of the book, I beginned witring $P: ax+by+cz=0$ as the plane containing $\alpha(0),\alpha(h_1),\alpha(h_2)$ (by item a) of the question we know that its limiting position is the osculating plane). The center $C$ of this circle $\Pi$ is given by the intersection of mediatrixs at $P$, with directions

$$v_1=(a,b,c)\wedge \alpha(h_1)\quad,\quad v_2=(a,b,c)\wedge\alpha(h_2)$$

Am I correct...?

Well, considering $|(a,b,c)|=1$, we obtain:

$$v_1\cdot v_2=\begin{vmatrix}|(a,b,c)|^2&0\\
0&\alpha(h_1)\cdot \alpha(h_2) \end{vmatrix}=\alpha(h_1)\cdot \alpha(h_2)$$

We ask for $k_1,k_2$ s.t.

$$\alpha(h_1)+v_1k_1=\alpha(h_2)+v_2k_2$$

I wrote some calculus from here but they are confused and I could not finish...

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the center should be $n(0)/k(0)$

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry, for a translation error I wrote center at $n(0)$ instead of "center at the line that contains $n(0)$". I fixed just now. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I get the answer by taking circle

$$C:(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2=r^2$$

instead of plane $P$,

defining

$$F(s)=(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2-r^2$$

and doing some derivatives and calculus of these kind ( [Derivatives of first/second order going to zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3353532/derivatives-of-first-second-order-going-to-zero)).

Many thanks for attention on topic and I am open to suggestions and corrections and still offer the bounty.

Comment: I calculate $F'(0)=-2a$ and $F''(0)=2-2\kappa b$ which using the mean value theorem like in part a gives us $a=0$ and $b=\frac{1}{\kappa}$. As we know the limit is in the oscilating plane from part a we get $c=0$ so the result follows.

Answer (score 2):

If $\alpha(0)$, $\alpha(h_1)$, and $\alpha(h_2)$ are three distinct non-aligned points, then there exist a unique circle passing through them. If $h_1,h_2$ are distinct and close enough to $0$, this is granted if $\kappa(0) \neq 0$.

This circle lies in the plane $\alpha(0) + span\{\alpha(h_1)-\alpha(0), \alpha(h_2)-\alpha(h_0)\}$.
Call $c$ the center of the circle and set:
\begin{align}
C:=&c-\alpha(0)\\
U:=&\alpha(h_1)-\alpha(0)\\
V:=&\alpha(h_2)-\alpha(0)\\
W:=&V-\dfrac{\langle V, U \rangle}{\langle U,U \rangle}U
\end{align}
Notice $W\neq 0$, since the three points $\alpha(0), \alpha(h_1), \alpha(h_2)$ are not aligned.
The fact $c$ is equidistant from $\alpha(0), \alpha(h_1), \alpha(h_2)$ corresponds to the following to the equations:
\begin{equation}
\Vert C \Vert^2 = \Vert C-U \Vert^2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\Vert C \Vert^2 = \Vert C-V \Vert^2
\end{equation}
Setting $C=aU+bW$ you can solve these equations to find $a,b$ and, therefore, the center of the circle (use the fact $U\perp W$). All you have to do now is taking the limit as $h_1,h_2\to 0$ with $h_1\neq h_2$. The Frenet formulas should be helpful. After long calculation you should be able to show what is claimed.

Comment: Thank you for this interesting suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Taking $F(s)=(x(s)-a)^2+(y(s)-b)^2+(z(s)-c)^2-r^2$ where $(a,b,c)$ is the center of a circle crossing $\alpha(0),\alpha(h_1),\alpha(h_2)$. Consider $F'(s)=2(x'(x-a)+y'(y-b)+z'(z-c))$ using local canonical form of $\alpha$ and taking the limit as $s$ approaches $0$ gives $F'(0)=-2a$. Similarly for $F''(s)=2(x''(x-a)+x'^2)+2(y''(y-b)+y'^2)+2(z''(z-c)+z'^2)$ we get $F''(0)=2-kc$. Using the mean value theorem twice and noticing $F(0)=F(h_1)=F(h_2)=0$ (and consequently points $F'(k_1)=F'(k_2)=0$ and $F''(j)=0$). If $h_1,h_2 \rightarrow 0$ then  $a\rightarrow 0$ and $b\rightarrow \frac{1}{k}$ we know from part a $c\rightarrow 0$ so we know the center is $\frac{n(0)}{k}$ as desired

Comment: I think this method can be  modified to solve the next problem by setting $G(s)=F\circ\pi(s)$ and noticing the mean value theorem implies there exist points such that $G'(k_1)=\frac{-\kappa\tau (h_1)^2}{6}$ and $G'(k_2)=\frac{-\kappa\tau (h_2)^2}{6}$ and $G''(j)=\frac{-\kappa\tau (h_1+h_2)}{6}$ which approach zero as $h_1,h_2\rightarrow 0$ so the conclusion $a\rightarrow 0$ and $b\rightarrow \frac{1}{k}$ holds for $G(s)$. However a mimic arguement using the circle defined by $\alpha\circ\pi(h_1)$ and $\alpha\circ\pi(h_1)$ gives $a\rightarrow 0$ and $b\rightarrow \frac{1}{k_{\pi}}$

Comment: It seems to me that your argument involves at least uniform convergence of $F_{h_1,h_2}$ to a function $F$, in order to conclude (for example) that $F'_{h_1,h_2}(k(h_1)) \to F'(0)$, so I was wondering how to prove that?

Comment: @LorenzoVanni Perhaps the differential curve is sufficiently nice so that the hypothesis of Dini's theorem apply and give uniform convergence.